# Difference between %255[^\0]s and %255c

Tags: c, format, scanf

In C, when using sscanf, for the format parameter, is there a difference between using:

```
%255[^\0]s
```

And:

```
%255c
```

Is one faster? Will one of the above ever give a different outcome?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is certainly *not* what the OP intended.

The OP requests the `sscanf(buf, format, dest)` difference between formats

```
"%255[^\0]s"  // a seemingly format specifier %255[^\0] and the letter 's'
"%255c"
```

Certainly the OP wanted the `sscanf(buf, format, dest)` difference between formats

```
"%255[^\0]"  // a seemingly format specifier %255[^\0]
"%255c"
```

**OR**

```
"%255s"  // format specifier %255s
"%255c"
```

The `"%255[^\0]"` is *not* the format one may think.   This is the *same* as format `"%255[^"`.  `sscanf()` does not know there is something past the explicit null character `'\0'`.  Since the format specifier begins with a `[` but does not end with a matching `]`, it is an invalid specifier.  "If a conversion specification is invalid, the **behavior is undefined**."

This also applies to the original `"%255[^\0]s"`:**behavior is undefined**.

Following are the salient issues between `"%255s"` and `"%255c"`

1. `"%255c"` *does not* consume leading white spaces.  `"%255s"` does consume unlimited leading white space, scanning them, but *not* saving them to `dest`.
2. `"%255c"` does scan white spaces and saves them to `dest`.  `"%255s"`, after it found a non-white space, will stop scanning should it encounter a white space.
3. Both will scan up to 255 characters and place the scanned characters into `dest`.
4. `"%255c"` does *not* append a `\0` so `dest` should cope with 255 `char`.
5. `"%255s"`, if it scans at least 1 char, will append a `\0`, so `dest` should cope with 256 `char`.
6. Neither will scan a `\0` as the scanning `buf` stops on `\0` in `sscanf()`.  `"%255c"` would scan a `\0` in `fscanf()`.  This is unusual as `fscanf()` is not used much when files have `\0` in them.

Should any speed difference occur, certainly it is implementation dependent.

Comment: Good catch with the `\0` bit.

Comment: +1: Compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -c x13.c`, you get warnings such as: `x13.c: In function ‘main’:` and
`x13.c:9: warning: no closing ‘]’ for ‘%[’ format` and
`x13.c:9: warning: embedded ‘\0’ in format`.  It isn't entirely clear what `scanf()` does, but anything is OK since the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for sure about speed, but there is a difference in outcome.

First, `%255c` will (assuming there's at least 255 characters in the string you're scanning) read 255 characters, regardless of what they are. `%255[^\0]s`, on the other hand, will read up to 255 *non-whitespace* characters.

Second, because strings are already terminated by `\0`, the `[^\0]` part of the regex is redundant, as `sscanf` will never consider null-terminators as part of the string.